# Unknown custom element: <v-main> Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I get error `Unknown custom element: <v-main> - did you register the component correctly?`
But all other Vuetify tags (v-app, v-app-bar, etc.) works correctly

I'm using VueJS + Vuetify + Laravel
`package.json`:

```
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"vuetify": "^2.2.30",
"vuex": "^3.4.0"
"vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
"vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.5",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
```

in `app.js`:

```
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.component('main-app', require("./MainApp").default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store,
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
});
```

Component:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-main>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

`.blade.php` file:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <main-app></main-app>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved by updating Vuetify to `"vuetify": "^2.3.9",`